# Show that $\dfrac{\partial(fg)}{\partial z}=\dfrac{\partial(f)}{\partial z}g+f\dfrac{\partial(g)}{\partial z}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Show that $$\frac{\partial(fg)}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial(f)}{\partial z}g+f\frac{\partial(g)}{\partial z}$$ where $f,g$ are $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable.

**Proof:**  Suppose that $f,g$ are $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable. From Calculus, we know that $fg$ is also $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable. i.e. For $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\dfrac{\partial(fg)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial(f)}{\partial x}g+f\dfrac{\partial(g)}{\partial x}$$

Now my gut says that proving this for the complex ($\mathbb{C}$) case isn't the same as the real ($\mathbb{R}$) proof. Am I right to trust my gut? How should I continue with this problem?

**Edit:** Suppose that $f,g$ are $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable. From Calculus, we know that $fg$ is also $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable. i.e. $f'$ and $g'$ exists for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Recall that $$\dfrac{\partial(fg)}{\partial z}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\partial(fg)}{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial(fg)}{\partial y}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\partial(fg)}{\partial x}+\dfrac{1}{i}\dfrac{\partial(fg)}{\partial y}\right).$$
With $f=u+iv$, $g=\alpha+i\beta$ for real-valued $u,v,\alpha,\beta$, then $fg=\alpha u-\beta v+i(\beta u+\alpha v)$, so 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{\partial(fg)}{\partial x} & = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(u\alpha-v\beta) +i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(u\beta+v\alpha) \\ 
& = \alpha \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
+ u \dfrac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}
-\beta \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}
- v \dfrac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}
+ i u \dfrac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}
+ i \beta \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}
+ i \alpha \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}
+ i v \dfrac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}\\
& = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\alpha+i\beta) 
+ \dfrac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}(u+iv)
+ \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}(-\beta+i\alpha) 
+ \dfrac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}(-v+iu)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Note $-\beta+i\alpha=i^2\beta+i\alpha=i(\alpha+i\beta)$ and similarly $-v+iu=i(u+iv)$. Then,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{\partial(fg)}{\partial x} 
& = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} g
+ \dfrac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x} f
+ i\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} g 
+ i\dfrac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} f \\
& = \left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
+ i\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} \right) g
+ \left(\dfrac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x} 
+ i\dfrac{\partial \beta}{\partial x} \right) f \\
& = g \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} (u+iv)
+ f \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} (\alpha + i\beta) \\
& = g \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} 
+ f \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Similarly, we can find
$$\frac{\partial(fg)}{\partial y} 
= g \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} 
+ f \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} $$
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial(fg)}{\partial z} & =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial(fg)}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial(fg)}{\partial y}\right) \\
& =\dfrac{1}{2}
\left(g \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} + f \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
+\dfrac{1}{i}\left(g \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + f \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)\right) \\
& =\dfrac{1}{2}
\left(g\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +\frac{1}{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) + f\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} +\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right) \right) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

How do I continue from here?

Comment: What the guy said is correct, because $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$ has its own definition which is different than merely $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $f=u+iv$, $g=\alpha+i\beta$ for real-valued $u,v,\alpha,\beta$, then $fg=\alpha u-\beta v+i(\beta u+\alpha v)$, so 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial(fg)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(\alpha u-\beta v)+i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(\beta u+\alpha v)=\cdots
\end{align*}
and in a routine way also,
\begin{align*}
g\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=(\alpha+i\beta)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(u+iv)=\cdots
\end{align*}
after a messy simplification, the result follows.

Note that
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}(fg)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(fg)+\dfrac{1}{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(fg)\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Do I need to prove that $f,g$ are complex differentiable?

Comment: Actually here there is no complex-differentiable issue taken into account. I mean, if you look at the definition of $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$, it is only the partial derivative of functions. Although the functions are complex-valued, we define the partial derivative in the canonical way: Spitting the partial derivative operator to the real and imaginary parts separately.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is there a deeper reason that you write $+\frac1i$ and not simply $-i$?

Comment: I am no complex-analyst, but I saw $\dfrac{1}{i}$ instead of $-i$ in many books such as *Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables* by R. Michael Range, and also in several Steven G. Krantz books either.

Comment: @user284331 I edited my original post. How should I proceed from the last step?

Comment: Then it is simply $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\dfrac{1}{i}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$...

Comment: Oh I see it I need to get the 1/2 inside the parenthesis and DONE! Thank you for the help!